# Где находится цикл вывода товаров в woocommerce?

Tags: циклы, woocommerce

Нужно список товаров обернуть в карусель. Не могу найти где находится цикл вывода товаров в woocommerce. 
Нашла начало списка в одном файле

```html
<ul class="products columns-<?php echo esc_attr( wc_get_loop_prop( 'columns' ) ); ?>">
```

и конец в другом файле

```html
</ul>
```

нашла где выводит один товар

```html
<li <?php wc_product_class(); ?>>
<?php
........
do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item' );
?>
</li>
```

а вот где сам цикл не могу найти.

Или может кто то знает как реализовать вывод товара после фильтра в виде слайдера.

Comment: Устанавливаю слайдеры для woocommerce выставляю шорткод на странице shop. Ничего не меняется. На других статических страницах , если добавить шорткод слайдер с товаром выводится.

Answer (score 0):

Все шаблоны вывода WooCommerce находятся в папке `templates` и её подпапках. В частности, страница архивов товаров (в том числе и главная страница магазина) выводятся через `woocommerce/templates/archive-product.php`.

Чтобы внести изменения в файл шаблона WooCommerce надо создать в дочерней теме папку `woocommerce` и в неё скопировать файл из папки `woocommerce/templates` плагина, сохраняя структуру (не учитывая папку templates). Например,

```
wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product/price.php
```

должен быть скопирован в

```
wp-content/themes/ваша-тема/woocommerce/single-product/price.php
```

Comment: Где находится template WooCommerce я знаю. У меня вопрос как добавить слайдер товаров на главную страницу WooCommerce

Comment: "Не могу найти где находится цикл вывода товаров в woocommerce" - я вам объяснил, где он находится.